# MySQL timeout counts even though script is running

Tags: mysql, database, python

I have 2 pairs of python scripts that run 24/7.  2 of them perform data insertions, 2 of them perform analysis.  What happens is when I look at the connections in MySQL Workbench the 2 performing the insertions have time counters that never get reset to zero.  The scripts performing the analysis are always on.  The problem comes when this count reaches 28800 I get the "MySQL Server has gone away" error for the insertion scripts but never for the analysis ones.

This seems very strange as the insertion scripts are running every 4-5 seconds.  The analysis ones are just looped and run forever continually.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you check wait_timeout on my.cnf ?
The default is 28800
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout